# Travelling Wave Solution For Fisher Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, mathematical-modeling, biology

I am working with the Fisher equation which I have non-dimensionalised as
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} +u(1-u)
\end{equation}

I am looking for travelling wave solutions for the previous equation. I let $u(x,t)=U(z)$ with $z=x-ct$ so that $c$ is the speed of the travelling wave with $x$ from -100 to 100. and sudying for $t \geq 0$. I found the second order ODE for $U(z) as from the last eq, this being
\begin{align}
U'=V
\end{align}
\begin{align}
V' = -cV - U(1-U)
\end{align}

This is the part that I am having issues with. I am given the following
$$
u_0(x)=u(x,0)= \frac{1}{(1 + \beta e^{\frac{x}{\sqrt{6}}})^2}
$$
For some positive parameter $\beta$. I must show that there is some unique $c$, and state it's value, such that $U(z)=u_0(z)$ for some arbitrary $\beta$.

I would appreciate any help with this problem or an approach that will lead me in the right direction. Thank you all in advance.

Comment: You'll need to tell us what you've tried. Have you read any books on the equation? Have you looked at the phase portrait? Have you tried substituting $U(z) = u_{0}(z)$ into the ODE system?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with what you found : $\quad\begin{cases}
U'=V\\
V' = -cV - U(1-U)
\end{cases}$
$$U''=-cU'-U(1-U)\tag 1$$
With initial condition :
$$
u_0(x)=u(x,0)= \frac{1}{(1 + \beta e^{\frac{x}{\sqrt{6}}})^2}=U(x) \tag 2
$$
because this condition must satisfy the ODE $(1)$.

$$U'(x)=\frac{-2}{(1 + \beta e^{\frac{x}{\sqrt{6}}})^3}\frac{\beta}{\sqrt{6}}e^{\frac{x}{\sqrt{6}}}\tag 3$$
$$U''(x)=\frac{1}{(1 + \beta e^{\frac{x}{\sqrt{6}}})^4}\beta^2e^{2\frac{x}{\sqrt{6}}})
-\frac{1}{3(1 + \beta e^{\frac{x}{\sqrt{6}}})^3}\beta e^{\frac{x}{\sqrt{6}}}\tag 4$$
Putting $(2),(3),(4)$ into equation $(1)$ after simplification leads to :
$$\frac{c\sqrt{3}-5}{3(1 + \beta e^{\frac{x}{\sqrt{6}}})^3}\beta e^{\frac{x}{\sqrt{6}}}=0$$
This can be satisfied any $\beta$ only with
$$c=\frac{5}{\sqrt{3}}$$

Comment: Thank you so much, however I've followed your method and got $c=\frac{5}{\sqrt{6}}$, is it possible there's a small error somewhere in your calculation that would account for this?

Comment: Possibly it's a typo in editing my answer. But I have deleted my calculus. Sorry, I don't like  to do the calculus again.